# invariant sub space

Tags: linear-algebra

So I preparing myself to a test in linear algebra and I scanned the last years test and I reached a question which I do not understand why is it like that.

True or false:

$ \forall T\colon V \rightarrow V$

$\exists 0_{V} \neq W \neq V $

so that $T(W) \in W$

So the answer is false and as example he gave this matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$

So how do u proof that for the above transformation there is no such a subspace ?

I know the answer is very trivial but I still do not get it.

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the question should rather read $T(W)\subseteq W$.

However, for the given matrix, the space spanned by the first basis vector *is* invariant, so that's not a counterexample.
An obvious counterexample would have been a case with $\dim V=1$ instead.

Comment: Ohh I get you mean something like: V is a vector space over the real then the linear map will be: T(a) = a+5 and because $0 < dimW < dimV=1$ (according to the answer conditions) we can conclude that $W$ does not exists. right ?

Comment: @wantToLearn You're right about the dimension inequalities, but your suggested $T$ is not a linear operator (which the question presumably intended).

Comment: Oh you are right. this is not a linear tranformation well then T(a) = a and this is much better. thanks a lot !!